# Retrieving the IP address of an EC2 instance given an instance ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Using the `aws CLI`, how can I retrieve the **private IP address** of an EC2 instance given its instanceID?

When I do:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids <instance_ID>
```

I get other information, but not the private IP addresses such as:

```
{
    "InstanceStatuses": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "XXXXX", 
            "InstanceState": {
                "Code": 16, 
                "Name": "running"
            }, 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a", 
            "SystemStatus": {
                "Status": "ok", 
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed", 
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "InstanceStatus": {
                "Status": "ok", 
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed", 
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `describe-instances` instead.  Private IP Address isn't returned with [describe-instance-status](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html) because that command describes system and instance status, primarily concerning itself with hardware/issues or scheduled events.

Per the ["Output" section of the describe-instances documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#output), part of the output of describe-instances is a string `PrivateIpAddress`.

Example usage:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <instance_ID>
```

Answer (score 5):

To get ALL private IP addresses:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} |\
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress'
```

or

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} |\
jq -r ".Reservations[]" | grep PrivateIpAddress |\
egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the query option.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --query Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress
```

This will just return the private IPAddress and no other output information