# Fetch the IP address of an instance after creating it

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal, aws-cli

I know there's this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243711/retrieving-the-ip-address-of-an-ec2-instance-given-an-instance-id) that has the pretty much the same question as mine, and I've followed the answer there however, it's not resulting in what I need.

I'm typing the following into the terminal:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-17xxxxxx5 | awk '/PrivateIpAddress/{print $2}'
```

And I get this output:

```
"10.96.2.194",
[
"10.96.2.194"
"10.96.2.194"
```

How can I just get `10.96.2.194`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do it across platforms or just want to use the built-in JSON query capabilities in AWSCLI, this would also work:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-17xxxxxx5 --query Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.. This is actually pretty awesome answer too!

Comment: You may need to add `--output text` in end to get the IP only.

Comment: With the default output format (``json``) the IP address will be in double-quotes.  With ``text`` output, there will be no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This grabs the first line that matches "PrivateIpAddress", prints the second field in that line, and strips out the quote and comma characters.

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-17xxxxxx5 | grep -m 1 PrivateIpAddress | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[",]//g'`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!

Comment: note the output format (json, table, etc) may change too.